# Is a satellite orbit around the Earth Lyapunov stable?

Tags: orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, stability, chaos-theory, complex-systems

Presume there is a satellite orbiting the Earth in an orbit that follows a closed path around the planet (that is, escape orbits are not permitted here).  As I understand it, there are two possibilities, ignoring the massive timescales that this might require:

1. The orbit can decay due to the action of the atmosphere
2. The orbit can expand until the satellite eventually leaves orbit.  As I understand it this happens with larger bodies, like moons, around planets, but not satellites.  I also could be wrong here.

Considering the $\langle x, y, z \rangle$ coordinates of the spacecraft in a suitable coordinate frame and their associated derivatives, in case 1 above the orbit would be stable in the sense that it decays to the origin of the state space, if the Earth were a point mass centered at the origin.  However, it isn't.  Would such an orbital decay still be Lyapunov stable?

Is case 2 possible?  In case 2 the orbit would be unstable in the sense of Lyapunov and just about everything else, correct?

Is there a 3rd case in which the orbits are actually stable in the sense that the coordinates in the state space are bounded and never zero?

Comment: Concerning Mechanism #2:  Moons can migrate outwards due to their tidal interactions with their planet, but this process is usually self-limiting, stopping once the planet becomes tidally locked with the moon.  An example where this has happened is the Pluto-Charon system.  (Not sure how/whether this applies to gas giants, though.)

Comment: Also, mechanism #3:  inspiral due to gravitational wave emission.